# Pass data to PHP file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to pass data to PHP file using Ajax and then save to MySQL database. From some reasons it's not working. I tested PHP code with passing data from HTML form and it's working. When use Ajax, after click on submit button nothings happen. I think that the problem is in Ajax data parameter.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form class="search" action="" method="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="trazi" name="trazi" placeholder="Pretražite artikle - upišite naziv, barkod ili šifru artikla">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form class="articles" id="novi_artikl" action="" method="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="sifra" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Šifra artikla</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="sifra" name="sifra" placeholder="Upišite šifru">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="barkod" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Barkod artikla</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="barkod" name="barkod" placeholder="Upišite barkod">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="naziv" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Naziv artikla</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="naziv" name="naziv" placeholder="Upišite naziv artikla" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="mjera" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Jedinična mjera</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="mjera" name="mjera" placeholder="Upišite mjeru" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="cijena" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Cijena artikla</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg text-right" id="cijena" name="cijena" placeholder="Upišite cijenu" required>
            <span class="input-group-addon">KM</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="kolicina" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Količina artikla</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg text-right" id="kolicina" name="kolicina" placeholder="Upišite količinu" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="ukupno" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Ukupna vrijednost artikla</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg text-right" id="ukupno" name="ukupno" placeholder="Ukupna vrijednost" required>
            <span class="input-group-addon">KM</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <br>
    <div class="float-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="spremi" name="spremi">Spremi</button>&nbsp;
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="ponisti" name="ponisti">Poništi</button>
    </div>
  </form><!-- Content here -->
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/38d56b17e3.js"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#spremi').click(function(){
var sifra = $('#sifra').val();
var barkod = $('#barkod').val();
var naziv = $('#naziv').val();
var mjera = $('#mjera').val();
var cijena = $('#cijena').val();
var kolicina = $('#kolicina').val();
var ukupno = $('#ukupno').val();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'insert.php',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:'json',
  data: ({sifra: sifra}, {barkod: barkod}, {naziv: naziv}, {mjera: mjera}, {cijena: cijena}, {kolicina: kolicina}, {ukupno: ukupno}),
  success: function(response){

    alert(response);
  }
});
});
```

PHP code

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if ($_POST["sifra"]) {
$sifra = $_POST["sifra"];
$barkod = $_POST["barkod"];
$naziv = $_POST["naziv"];
$mjera = $_POST["mjera"];
$cijena = $_POST["cijena"];
$kolicina = $_POST["kolicina"];
$ukupno = $_POST["ukupno"];

$query = "INSERT INTO lista (sifra, barkod, naziv, mjera, cijena, kolicina, ukupno) VALUES ('$sifra', '$barkod', '$naziv', '$mjera', '$cijena', '$kolicina', '$ukupno')";

$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if($results){
  echo "Artikl je uspješno spremljen.";
}
else {
  echo "Artikl nije spremljen. Došlo je do pogreške.";
}
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: use  `data: {sifra: sifra, barkod: barkod, naziv: naziv, mjera: mjera, cijena: cijena, kolicina: kolicina, ukupno: ukupno}` instead. I.e pass a single object, not a bunch of objects...

Comment: What's your files structure? i.e the where and name of the html form file and the processor file? Also, what is the output of your browser's console? Does it release any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is the fact you are using `type: 'POST'`.  To quote the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) :

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the
>   HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or
>   multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request.

POST is a more "old fashioned" method, typically you would POST a `<form>` where the content automatically is *serialized*, i.e urlencoded, but you try to POST data in a JSON format. What you should do is either consider whether you really need POST. If you change it to GET (or simply remove `type: 'POST'`) and access the passed data by `$_GET` then it will work (as long as you correct `data` as well).

If not, change the content type to indicate incoming urlencoded data :

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'insert.php',
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  data: {sifra: sifra, barkod: barkod, naziv: naziv, mjera: mjera, cijena: cijena, kolicina: kolicina, ukupno: ukupno},
  success: function(response){
    alert(response);
  }
});
```

I am pretty sure your code will work now, i.e the $_POST works and any message is properly received as plain text you can alert.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide the values to the `data` property of `$.ajax` as a single object not as a collection of them:

```
data: {
  sifra: sifra, 
  barkod: barkod,
  naziv: naziv,
  mjera: mjera,
  cijena: cijena,
  kolicina: kolicina,
  ukupno: ukupno
},
```

Also, it's very important that you note your PHP code is *wide open to SQL injection attacks*. You should change the logic to use prepared statements ASAP.

Comment: @Josip, what exactly is not working? A third issue you have is  `dataType:'json'` but you pass back plain text, this will defently raise an AJAX error, but the question is, is the data inserted to the db or not?

Comment: No, data is not inserted to db, that is the problem.